# Creating a plugin tutorial

Tags: qgis, python, qgis-plugins, plugins

I am looking for a tutorial of how to create a plugin for QGIS.

I want a tutorial that:

1. Explains about the latest version of QGIS
2. Working in windows environment.
3. adequate for absolute beginners and explains step by step.

A search on the web brought up a few tutorials but none of them answers all requirements.

p.s.
I have knowledge in python programming.

Can anyone help with finding such a tutorial?

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a short getting started based on the plugin builder plugin http://anitagraser.com/2014/04/26/getting-started-writing-qgis-2-x-plugins/.
While I work on Windows, it's not very specific to the operating system.

Do you mean absolute GIS beginners, absolute programming beginners, absolute Python beginners, or absolute QGIS beginners? :D 
It needs more than a simple tutorial to get non-programmers started. The [**PyQGIS Programmer's Guide** book by Gary Sherman](https://locatepress.com/ppg) might be suitable since it starts with the very basics.

Answer (score 2):

I've also written an extented tutorial for qgis plugin creation. check it out here: http://www.digital-geography.com/build-qgis-plugin/